# How to split a very large string into an array of smaller strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, split

I do have a very long string like:

```
$largestring = a,b,c,d,e,f,........
```

I want it as:

```
$smallstrarray = (a,b,c,d), (e,f,g,h), (I,j,k,l).
```

I need to parse this string to server, as my server capacity is not enough to handle a very large string.
I have tried implode but I could not find a proper and short solution with it.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to `explode`/`implode` the large string?  how big is this string?  Does the string come from a file?

Comment: You could use a loop and `array_slice()` to do that

Comment: Thnx all for your comments. This is my first question that I posted so could be less explained. I think @LewisHai my own answer have cleared the things more.

Answer (score -1):

I got it. I just used following code and got it done:-

```
$large_string = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,....
$str_array = explode(',',$large_string);
for ($i =0 ; $i<=$str_array.length; $i++){
                    $subArray = array_chunk($str_array, 100);
                   foreach($subArray as $array){
                      $small_string = implode(",",$array);
                       passToServer($small_string);
                   }
```

If any of you guys have any better idea, plz responde

Comment: `$str_array.length` #ThatAin'tNoPHPBro - If you're going to anser your own question, at least answer it with valid code

Comment: thank you all for your comments; this one was my first question with bad experience :)